# Django summing values over past 10 weeks for each week

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Given a date how can you sum the total of the week that date falls in and each of the 10 weeks previous?

For each day in the last 30 this can be accomplished by:

```
import datetime as dt
from django.db.models import Sum

last_30 = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=30)
order_data = Order.objects.filter(
    date__gt=last_30).extra(
    select={'day': 'date(date)'}.values('day').annotate(
    total=Sum('total')
)

print(order_data)

<OrderQuerySet [{'day': datetime.date(2018, 8, 28), 'total': Decimal('50000.00'), 
                {'day': datetime.date(2018, 8, 29), 'total': Decimal('84000.00'), 
                '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

I guess they could also somehow be grouped into weeks after the fact by looping through `order_data` but I was wondering if there's another way.

Using postgresql if that makes a difference.

Comment: Does a week starts on sunday, or monday?

Comment: By selecting 30 days, this also means that for the first week, we will only consider a subset of the week, as well as the most recent week.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah, if I went the route of grouping into weeks based on `order_data` then I would probably use `days=70` and make `today` the last day in this "week"... I apologize if that's confusing, all I'm trying to say is the start and end of each week doesn't matter as long as it remains consistent for the previous 10. If accomplished with sql then the natural week is fine even if the current week isn't a full week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Django's [**`ExtractWeek`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractWeek) to obtain the week number of a date. So we can first annotate the queryset, and then pass the correct values, like:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeek

qs = Order.objects.filter(date__gt=last_70).annotate(
    week=ExtractWeek('date')
).values('week').annotate(
    week_total=Sum('total')
).order_by('week')
```

This will produce something like:

```
<QuerySet [
    { 'week': 14, 'week_total': 1425.0 }
    { 'week': 15, 'week_total': 1302.0 }
    { 'week': 17, 'week_total': 1993.0 }
]>
```

Note that

1. the `.order_by` is important, since otherwise the values will *not* "fold";
2. if there are no rows for a specific week, these will *not* be in the queryset, so it might require some post-processing, to introduce zeros for that;
3. as [per source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/functions/datetime/#ExtractWeek), it uses *Monday* as the first day of the week;
4. since you filter the dataset, the *earliest* week, will only sum over a *subset* of that week (the days that are not "too old"), this thus will result in the fact that that sum of that week will not match with all the days that week.